# Show that the following inequalities are satisfied.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Show that $\|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and that equalities can occur for nonzero vectors.

Given
\begin{align*}
\|x\|_\infty &= \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |x_i|,\\ 
\|x\|_2 &= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2},\\ 
\|x\|_1 &= \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|.
\end{align*}
We first want to prove $\|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_2$. Without loss of generality, lets assume that the maximum is obtained for $i=1$. We then have
$$\|x\|_\infty = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |x_i| = |x_1|= \sqrt{x_1^2}.$$
Now, for each $i = 1,2, \ldots, n$, we have $x_i^2 > 0$. Thus,
$$\|x\|_\infty =|x_1| = \sqrt{x_1^2} \leq \sqrt{x_1^2 + \sum_{i=2}^nx_i^2} =\|x\|_2,$$
that is, $\|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_2$. Now, to prove $\|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_1$, we define
$$x^{(k)} = (0,0,\ldots,x_k,\ldots,0) \quad \forall k = 1,2, \ldots, n.$$
Then
$$x = \sum_{k=1}^nx^{(k)},$$
and
$$\|x\|_2 = \left\|\sum_{k=1}^nx^{(k)}\right\| \underbrace{\leq}_{\text{triangle inequality}} \sum_{k=1}^n||x^{(k)}||_2 = \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{\left(x^{(k)}\right)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n|x^{(k)}| = \|x\|_1.$$
Finally, set $x = (x_1, 0,0 \ldots, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for $x_1 \neq 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
\|x\||_\infty &= \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |x_i| = |x_1|,\\ 
\|x\|_2 &= \sqrt{x_1^2} = |x_1|,\\
\|x\|_1 &= |x_1|,
\end{align*}
therefore the equalities can occur for non-zero vectors.

> Show that $\|x\|_1 \leq n \|x\|_\infty$ and $\|x\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \|x\|_\infty$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

To see the first inequality, we have that for each $i = 1,2,\ldots,n$, the inequality
$$|x_i| \leq \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |x_i|,$$ 
holds. This means that 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n|x_i| \leq n \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |x_i|,$$
and it follows that $\|x\|_1 \leq n\|x\|_\infty$. To see the other inequality, we have 
$$\max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |x_i| = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \sqrt{x_i^2}.$$
Now, on the other hand,
$$\|x\|_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \text{ and } \|x\|_\infty^2 = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} x_i^2.$$
By a similar reasoning, we have that for each $i = 1,2,\ldots,n$, the inequality
$$x_i^2 \leq \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} x_i^2,$$ 
holds. Therefore,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \leq n \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} x_i^2.$$
We now take the square roots to get
$$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \leq \sqrt{n} \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \sqrt{x_i^2},$$
that is, $\|x\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \|x\|_\infty$. Is this the right reasoning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything is correct.

Comment: You're welcome :)